# Orderby date column PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like this:

| Title | Date |
| --- | --- |
| The Last Kingdom | 19/03/2022 |
| The Wither | 15/02/2022 |

I want to create a new column with only the month and year and order by it. 19/03/2022 would be 03-2022

I created the column like this:

```
netflix_df = (netflix_df
                 .withColumn('month', F.substring(F.col("Date"), 4, 9))
                 .withColumn("month", F.regexp_replace(F.col("month"), '/', '-'))
               )
```

Resulting in:

| Title | Date | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The Last Kingdom | 19/03/2022 | 03-2022 |
| The Wither | 15/02/2022 | 02-2022 |

But when I do:

```
display(netflix_df.orderBy(F.col("month")))
```

Gives the error:

```
ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below logic (it is more concise). You essentially convert `string` to `date` then using `date_format` take month as `MM-yyyy` -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [('The Last Kingdom', '19/03/2022'), ('The Wither', '15/02/2022')], schema = ["Title", "Date"])

display(df.withColumn("month", date_format(to_date(col('Date'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'MM-yyyy')).orderBy(col("month")))
```

**Output** -

```
+----------------+----------+-------+
|Title           |Date      |month  |
+----------------+----------+-------+
|The Wither      |15/02/2022|02-2022|
|The Last Kingdom|19/03/2022|03-2022|
+----------------+----------+-------+
```